# Is there a keyboard shortcut to have Google correct one misspelled word?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts, spell-check

When I look at the [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for Google Docs, there are shortcuts listed to move forward and backwards between misspelt words, which work.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to fix a misspelt word?

Right now, I find myself having to use my mouse to right click on the word and then scroll up to select the spelling.

Is there any keyboard shortcut that just replaces the spelling with the correct word?

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/773961/chrome-browser-keyboard-shortcut-to-correct-spelling-of-word) on Super User is essentially the same as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends if you have a good keyboard. there is so-called **Menu Key** and usually sits on the right side next to **<kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd>** key - **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key**

[image]
[image]

however, if you don't have anything like that on your keyboard you can use a shortcut for that which is **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>F10</kbd>**

so the final combo should be:

- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>'</kbd>** **/** **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>;</kbd>** **...** **<kbd>≣ MENU KEY</kbd>** **...** **<kbd>ARROW DOWN</kbd>** **...** **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**
- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>'</kbd>** **/** **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>;</kbd>**  **...** **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>F10</kbd>** **...** **<kbd>ARROW DOWN</kbd>** **...** **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**